# Find all records that share specific comment

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, subquery

I have an existing `table1`:

```
User   Comment  Group
---------------------
1      foo      a
2      bar      a
3      baz      b
4      123      a
5      bar      c
6      foo      d
7      654      a
```

Assume that I need to select all `User`s with `Comment` `foo`

```
select * from [table1] t1 where t1.[Comment] = 'foo';

User   Comment   Group
---------------------
1      foo       a
6      foo       d
```

Now I want to find all the users in the same `Group`s:

```
User   Comment  Group
---------------------
1      foo      a
2      bar      a
4      123      a
6      foo      d
```

How can I do this? I thought like this:

```
select t1.*
from   [table1] t1
left join [table1] t2 on t1.[User] = t2.[User]
and t1.[Comment] = 'foo'
```

But this is returning all records in `[table1]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.comment = 'foo' and t1.group = t.group
)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(comment, group)`.

Answer (score 3):

With the operator `IN`:

```
select * from tablename
where [Group] in (
  select [Group] from tablename
  where [Comment] = 'foo'
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ebf40e0c46978e94dc3a387dce90b23b).
Results:

```
> User | Comment | Group
> ---: | :------ | :----
>    1 | foo     | a    
>    2 | bar     | a    
>    4 | 123     | a    
>    6 | foo     | d    
>    7 | 654     | a
```